# アンケートサイト作成しています

Tags: php, wordpress, ajax, pdo

各記事ごとにAjaxでデータベース通信しています。
AjaxのPostにsiteurl/enquete.phpで、データベースはwp/enqtableでPDOです。
記事生成時はすでにデータベースにあるアンケート質問をWordpress記事にコピペしてinputで回答します。

閲覧者が回答した瞬間にアンケート結果をAjaxで出力します。

この一連のやり方は適切でしょうか？
初めてなので、根本的に間違っている部分が無いか知りたいです。
よろしくお願いします。

他に考えられるやり方は、Ajaxを使うのでphpをheader javascriptにしなければなりませんが、WordPressというPHPを使っているので、そのままWordPressでPHPデータベース接続すれば良いのか？です。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

回答がありませんので、根本的に間違っている部分は無い、これでよいと判断しました。
ありがとうございました。